# How to use the XML jQuery api documentation in netbeans or other ides

Tags: jquery

I have downloaded the jquery api in the xml format but I don't know how to use it in Netbeans or other ides for code completion or any other purpose.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A [quick Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20api%20in%20netbeans) will give you the [instructions to make this happen](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/js-toolkits-jquery.html#addingjquery).